# How to start designing with Html Stream Snippets

Tags: html, node.js, npm, bootstrap-4

I've found a website named [Html Stream](https://htmlstream.com)
which provides a lot of free Html + Bootstrap snippets and also premium templates.
But as the snippets are free to use.

I'm stuck in its installation

**For Example :**
This is the link for the snippets [Html Stream Snippets](https://htmlstream.com/front/snippets/index.html)
And what I'm trying to do is to `Create a Header with Top Bar` which is given [here](https://htmlstream.com/front/snippets/headers/with-topbar.html)

But I'm not able to do that because I don't know where the `CSS Files` and `JS Plugins` are

**Here are the included CSS Files**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/vendor/hs-mega-menu/dist/hs-mega-menu.min.css">
```

**And these are the js files**

```
<!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->
<script src="./assets/vendor/hs-header/dist/hs-header.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/vendor/hs-mega-menu/dist/hs-mega-menu.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/vendor/hs-unfold/dist/hs-unfold.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/vendor/hs-show-animation/dist/hs-show-animation.min.js"></script>

<!-- JS Front -->
<script src="./assets/js/hs.validation.js"></script>
```

I also downloaded the UI Kits from [Html Stream Github Repo](https://github.com/htmlstreamofficial) but these files are not present in any of the 3 kits.

I've also installed `node js` and also tried `gulp` but still didn't find anything.
And this is the [Documentation](https://htmlstream.com/front/documentation/index.html)

I also followed the installation step [here](https://htmlstream.com/front/documentation/gulp.html) but its too confusing.

Don't know what to do?